# Invalid syntax error in code

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to run this code for the first time and getting a syntax error on line 21. Not really sure where this is coming from since I haven't done much before that in the code.

```
#defining the read method
def read():
    #opening data from first line
    pulsars = open("pulsars1.txt","r")
    #opening data from second line
    signals = open("signals1.txt","r")
    #creating a new empty list
    astro_list = []
    #reading pulsar line by line/turns all of this into string
    pulsar_data = pulsars.read()
    #reading signal data/turns all of this into string
    signal_data = signals.read()
    #appending pulsar values to list
    for all_pulsar_data in range(0,len(pulsar_data)):
        astro_list.append(pulsar_data)
    #appending signal data to list
    for all_signal_data in range(0,len(signal_data)):
        astro_list.append(signal_data)
    return(astro_list)
#defining the main function
def main():
    #displaying a descriptiong of what the program does
    purpose = "This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory"
    underheading = "=" * len(purpose)
    print(purpose)
    print(underheading)
    print("It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength, \nthen combines them and displays the results.")
    #accepting inputs from the user about file names
    pulsar_name = input("\nPulsar name file: ")
    signal_strength = input("Signal strength: ")
    #reading values
    print("\nAnalyzing data from" , pulsar_name, "and", signal_strength, "files...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,pulsar_name,"...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,signal_strength,"...")
    print("     ","Combining values...")
    #displaying the top part of the table
    astro_list = read()
    count_head= "\n The combined BOOYA data includes", len(astro_list), "values."
    print(count_head)
    print("=" * len(count_head))
    print(astro_list)
```

Comment: Fixed unresolved variables and undefined varialbes

Answer (score 0):

If you open up a file like this in PyCharm it becomes very obvious where the mistakes are. Hopefully this helps!

```
# defining the read function
def read():
    #opening data from first line
    pulsars = open("pulsars1.txt","r")
    #opening data from second line
    signals = open("signals1.txt","r")
    #creating a new empty list
    astro_list = []
    #reading pulsar line by line/turns all of this into string
    pulsar_data = pulsars.read()
    #reading signal data/turns all of this into string
    signal_data = signals.read()
    #appending pulsar values to list
    for all_pulsar_data in range(0,len(pulsar_data)):
        astro_list.append(pulsar_data)
    #appending signal data to list
    for all_signal_data in range(0,len(signal_data)):
        astro_list.append(signal_data)
    return(astro_list)


#defining the main function
def main():
    astro_list = read()
    #displaying a descriptiong of what the program does
    purpose = "This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory"
    underheading = "=" * len(purpose)
    print(purpose)
    print(underheading)
    print("It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength, \nthen combines them and displays the results.")
    #accepting inputs from the user about file names
    pulsar_name = input("\nPulsar name file: ")
    signal_strength = input("Signal strength: ")
    #reading values
    print("\nAnalyzing data from" , pulsar_name, "and", signal_strength, "files...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,pulsar_name,"...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,signal_strength,"...")
    print("     ","Combining values...")
    #displaying the top part of the table
    count_head= "\n The combined BOOYA data includes", len(astro_list), "values."
    print(count_head)
    print("=" * len(count_head))
    print(astro_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I made the adjustments you suggested but now when I run it i get a crazy amount of values that basically never end in printing, and the table doesnt even print out at all.

Comment: @MinnaAdelRubio Your question was about a `SyntaxError`, which this answer solved. I have no access to the files `pulsars1.txt` or `signals1.txt` so it is impossible for me to actually run the script properly. I'd be happy to try and help solve those issues in another question but it seems slightly off-topic for this one, no?

Comment: sure, I'm going to make a new question for this because I've changed some parts of the code..

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
for all pulsar_data in range(0, len(pulsar_data)**<-**):
    astro_list.append(pulsar_data)
```

Comment: There are more problems than that. For example, you missed that `all` has a space before `pulsar_data` as well. Not to mention the backticks and the fact that `astro_list` doesn't exist yet in `main` and is also misspelled when it is initialized in `read`. These are all fixed in my answer below.

Comment: Another critical issue is astro_list only defined in first def but not in second one.

Comment: It is actually defined as `astr_list` in the `read` function (misspelled) but I mentioned that already in my original reply. All of these issues are fixed in my answer though.